# Send get data again to another page in php

Tags: php, post, get, python-requests

In my website I have some url like

example.com/test/test?name=dd&type=a

I want to send data again to another page like:-

example.com/test/test/again?name=dd&type=a

How can I send data to /again from /test tell me please

Comment: When do you want to send data to another page, on a User Click or any other event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to store the data from get variables

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
```

Now assuming you want to send this data to `page2` on  button click

```
<form method="get" action="page2.php">
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="type" value="<?php echo $type;?>">
      <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Do the same for getting those variable at `page2`

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
```

Hope this will help you!